# Check if an option exist in select element without JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html

Unfortunately I don't have access to JQuery and all it's nicety.  But I do have access to JavaScript.  How do I check if an OPTION exist in a HTML Select?

EDIT:  To clarify, I need to know if an option exist.  So for example:

```
<select>
 <option>Volvo</option>
 <option>Saab</option>
 <option>Mercedes</option>
 <option>Audi</option>
</select>
```

I check if "Hyndai" is an OPTION, and it is not.

Comment: You want to check if a *particular* `option` exists, or just check that there is *at least one* `option` in the `select` element? And, incidentally, you'll need to use JavaScript for this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("myselect").options[0] //accesses first option via options[]
```

would select the first option in your select. If it fails you know that there are no options in your select. If you get data by appending `.value` after the `.options[0]` it's not empty. Without javascript you will not be able to achieve this. Only HTML does not deliver the functionality you want.

```
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById("myselect").length; ++i){
    if (document.getElementById("myselect").options[i].value == "Hyndai"){
      alert("Hyndai is available");
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I need to check if a specific option exist?  Not if any option exist?

Comment: what do you mean by specific option ?

Comment: Added clarification, please check.

Comment: I would recommend you to use jQuery for this purpose it would make your solution a lot easier and I could provide you a solution. pure javascript  is a bit more complicated for that.

Comment: I wish I could but I simply do not have access to JQuery for this project.  Look, sometimes, constraint are dictated by your Clients (or boss) and you don't really have a say.

Comment: I have edited my answer and it should provide the functionality you are looking for, hopefully it does :-)

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this issue today and used these answers to come up with my own, which I think is a little easier to use.

I loop through the `select`'s options (caching the length), but I put that loop into the HTMLSelectElement itself through it's prototype, as a `.contains()` function.

```
HTMLSelectElement.prototype.contains = function( value ) {

    for ( var i = 0, l = this.options.length; i < l; i++ ) {

        if ( this.options[i].value == value ) {

            return true;

        }

    }

    return false;

}
```

Then to use it, I simply write this:

```
if ( select.contains( value ) ) {
```

Comment: Brilliant, code to insert into its own js file for extending every Select element

Answer (score 5):

I understand there is already a chosen answer but for other people getting here from searching, I believe the accepted answer can be improved, by for example caching the selection of 'myselect'.

I think wrapping the logic in a reusable function and passing it the option you are looking for and the  object would make sense:

```
/**
 * Return if a particular option exists in a <select> object
 * @param {String} needle A string representing the option you are looking for
 * @param {Object} haystack A Select object
*/
function optionExists ( needle, haystack )
{
    var optionExists = false,
        optionsLength = haystack.length;

    while ( optionsLength-- )
    {
        if ( haystack.options[ optionsLength ].value === needle )
        {
            optionExists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return optionExists;
}
```

Usage:

```
optionExists( 'searchedOption', document.getElementById( 'myselect' ) );
```

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for a better solution than mine:

```js
[...document.querySelector("select").options].map(o => o.value).includes("Hyndai")
```

Comment: Love one-liners, but might be good to include some additional details on what exactly the code does. What does the ellipses at the beginning do?

Answer (score 3):

### Check for `value` attribute

Use the `value` property on the [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement) object to check if there is an option with the specified value attribute. Note that an option's value will fall back to its text content if no such attribute is provided.

```js
const select = document.querySelector("select");
const optionLabels = Array.from(select.options).map((opt) => opt.value);
const hasOption = optionLabels.includes("Hyndai");
```

Based on [Miguel Pynto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63563341/937377)

### Check for `<option>` display text

To instead check whether an option exists with specified display text, regardless of its `value` attribute, use the `text` property on the [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement) object. The only difference between these two snippets is the end of the second line.

```js
const select = document.querySelector("select");
const optionLabels = Array.from(select.options).map((opt) => opt.text);
const hasOption = optionLabels.includes("Hyndai");
```

[Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14976638/937377)

Answer (score 2):

Because I'm going to add an option to the select if it doesn't currently exist, I simply set the Select's value to the item I want to check exists, then read the element's selectedIndex property.  If it's -1, then the option doesn't currently exist in the control.

```
<select id="mySelect">
 <option>Apple</option>
 <option>Orange</option>
 <option>Pineapple</option>
 <option>Banana</option>
</select>

<script>
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("mySelect").value = "Banana";
 alert(document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex);
 //yields 3
 document.getElementById("mySelect").value = "Strawberry";
 alert(document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex);
 //yields -1
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to utilize `Array.prototype.find`:

```javascript
  /**
   * @param {HTMLSelectElement} selectElement
   * @param {string} optionValue
   * @return {boolean}
   */
  function optionExists(selectElement, optionValue) {
      return !!Array.prototype.find.call(selectElement.options, function(option) {
          return option.value === optionValue;
      }
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Add id to select and values to options:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="Value">Volvo</option>
    <option value="Saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Then:

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").querySelector("option[value='Hyndai'") // returns null
document.getElementById("mySelect").querySelector("option[value='Saab'") // returns element as object
!!document.getElementById("mySelect").querySelector("option[value='Hyndai'") // returns false
!!document.getElementById("mySelect").querySelector("option[value='Saab'") // returns true
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `document.querySelector("#mySelect [value='Hyndai']")`