# Get selected option text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list like this:

```
<select id="box1">
<option value="98">dog</option>
<option value="7122">cat</option>
<option value="142">bird</option>
</select>
```

How can I get the actual option text rather than the value using JavaScript?  I can get the value with something like:

```
<select id="box1" onChange="myNewFunction(this.selectedIndex);" >
```

But rather than `7122` I want `cat`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/1339473 see this for more help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the selected value of dropdownlist using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript) -- despite the title, it answers your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the text of the selected <option> in <select> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610336/retrieving-the-text-of-the-selected-option-in-select-element)

Answer (score 428, accepted):

Try options

```js
function myNewFunction(sel) {
  alert(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

```html
<select id="box1" onChange="myNewFunction(this);">
  <option value="98">dog</option>
  <option value="7122">cat</option>
  <option value="142">bird</option>
</select>
```

Comment: First rule when trying to use regex—keep searching Stack Overflow until you see the solution that doesn't need regex—cheers :)

Comment: It's more clean to write onchange without a capital c

Comment: Where's the `multiple` HTML select tag scenario?

Comment: I would say today's preferred way is to use [`selectedOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions). That also solves @Nitrodist 's problem.

Answer (score 195):

Plain JavaScript

```
var sel = document.getElementById("box1");
var text= sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
```

jQuery:

```
$("#box1 option:selected").text();
```

Comment: @mplungjan Why don't you comment here that jQuery uses `.textContent` and `.innerText` for `.text()` method operation? It is not by standards, it is totally wrong because it doesn't use `.text`. Where are the downvotes?

Comment: @mplungjan It is not `innerHTML`, `innerText` is even worse.

Comment: I see option: { get: function( elem ) {
    var val = elem.attributes.value;
    return !val || val.specified ? elem.value : elem.text;}
in 1.9

Answer (score 31):

## There are two solutions, as far as I know.

> both that just need using vanilla javascript

### 1 selectedOptions

> live demo

```js
const log = console.log;
const areaSelect = document.querySelector(`[id="area"]`);

areaSelect.addEventListener(`change`, (e) => {
  // log(`e.target`, e.target);
  const select = e.target;
  const value = select.value;
  const desc = select.selectedOptions[0].text;
  log(`option desc`, desc);
});
```

```html
<div class="select-box clearfix">
  <label for="area">Area</label>
  <select id="area">
    <option value="101">A1</option>
    <option value="102">B2</option>
    <option value="103">C3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

### 2 options

> live demo

```js
const log = console.log;
const areaSelect = document.querySelector(`[id="area"]`);

areaSelect.addEventListener(`change`, (e) => {
  // log(`e.target`, e.target);
  const select = e.target;
  const value = select.value;
  const desc = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
  log(`option desc`, desc);
});
```

```html
<div class="select-box clearfix">
  <label for="area">Area</label>
  <select id="area">
    <option value="101">A1</option>
    <option value="102">B2</option>
    <option value="103">C3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

---

Answer (score 24):

All these functions and random things, I think it is best to use this, and do it like this:

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].text
```

Answer (score 17):

*HTML:*

```
<select id="box1" onChange="myNewFunction(this);">
```

*JavaScript:*

```
function myNewFunction(element) {
    var text = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
    // ...
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/6dkun/1/

Comment: see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976495/get-selected-option-text-with-javascript/14976657#comment21029956_14976657) I removed our conversation since you fixed your code

Comment: Nice one, I spent several hours trying to find this answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use -

```
$.trim($("select").children("option:selected").text())   //cat
```

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/eEGr3/

Comment: Where does the question mention jQuery?

Answer (score 6):

ECMAScript 6+

```
const select = document.querySelector("#box1");

const { text } = [...select.options].find((option) => option.selected);
```

Answer (score 5):

Using vanilla JavaScript

```js
onChange = { e => e.currentTarget.options[e.selectedIndex].text }
```

will give you exact value if values are inside a loop.

Comment: Did you mean to say Java, or JavaScript?

Comment: needs to have `e.currentTarget.selectedIndex` in there i.e 
 `e.currentTarget.options[e.currentTarget.selectedIndex]`

Answer (score 4):

To get it on React with Typescript:

```
  const handleSelectChange: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLSelectElement> = (event) => {
    const {  options, selectedIndex } = event.target;
    const text = options[selectedIndex].text;
    // Do something...
  };
```

Answer (score 4):

Using jquery.
In your event

```
  let selText = $("#box1 option:selected").text();
  console.log(selText);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function runCode() {
  var value = document.querySelector('#Country').value;
  window.alert(document.querySelector(`#Country option[value=${value}]`).innerText);
}
```

```html
<select name="Country" id="Country">
   <option value="IN">India</option>
   <option value="GBR">United Kingdom </option>
   <option value="USA">United States </option>
   <option value="URY">Uruguay </option>
   <option value="UZB">Uzbekistan </option>
</select>

<button onclick="runCode()">Run</button>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can get an array-like object that contains the selected item(s) with the method `getSelected()` method. like this:

```
querySelector('#box1').getSelected()
```

so you can extract the text with the `.textContent` attribute. like this:

```
querySelector('#box1').getSelected()[0].textContent
```

If you have a multiple selection box you can loop through array-like object
I hope it helps you

Answer (score 2):

var selectionlist=document.getElementById("agents");
td2.innerHTML = selectionlist.children[selectionlist.selectedIndex].innerHTML;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You'll need to get the innerHTML of the option, and not its value.</strike>

Use `this.innerHTML` instead of `this.selectedIndex`.

Edit: You'll need to get the option element first and then use innerHTML.

Use `this.text` instead of `this.selectedIndex`.

Comment: This is wrong. It will grap the `innerHTML` of `<select>` element.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <select class="cS" onChange="fSel2(this.value);">
     <option value="0">S?lectionner</option>
     <option value="1">Un</option>
     <option value="2" selected>Deux</option>
     <option value="3">Trois</option>
 </select>

 <select id="iS1" onChange="fSel(options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
     <option value="0">S?lectionner</option>
     <option value="1">Un</option>
     <option value="2" selected>Deux</option>
     <option value="3">Trois</option>
 </select><br>

 <select id="iS2" onChange="fSel3(options[this.selectedIndex].text);">
     <option value="0">S?lectionner</option>
     <option value="1">Un</option>
     <option value="2" selected>Deux</option>
     <option value="3">Trois</option>
 </select>

 <select id="iS3" onChange="fSel3(options[this.selectedIndex].textContent);">
     <option value="0">S?lectionner</option>
     <option value="1">Un</option>
     <option value="2" selected>Deux</option>
     <option value="3">Trois</option>
 </select>

 <select id="iS4" onChange="fSel3(options[this.selectedIndex].label);">
     <option value="0">S?lectionner</option>
     <option value="1">Un</option>
     <option value="2" selected>Deux</option>
     <option value="3">Trois</option>
 </select>

 <select id="iS4" onChange="fSel3(options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML);">
     <option value="0">S?lectionner</option>
     <option value="1">Un</option>
     <option value="2" selected>Deux</option>
     <option value="3">Trois</option>
 </select>

 <script type="text/javascript"> "use strict";
   const s=document.querySelector(".cS");

 // options[this.selectedIndex].value
 let fSel = (sIdx) => console.log(sIdx,
     s.options[sIdx].text, s.options[sIdx].textContent, s.options[sIdx].label);

 let fSel2= (sIdx) => { // this.value
     console.log(sIdx, s.options[sIdx].text,
         s.options[sIdx].textContent, s.options[sIdx].label);
 }

 // options[this.selectedIndex].text
 // options[this.selectedIndex].textContent
 // options[this.selectedIndex].label
 // options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML
 let fSel3= (sIdx) => {
     console.log(sIdx);
 }
 </script> // fSel
```

But :

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> "use strict";
    const x=document.querySelector(".cS"),
          o=x.options, i=x.selectedIndex;
    console.log(o[i].value,
                o[i].text , o[i].textContent , o[i].label , o[i].innerHTML);
 </script> // .cS"
```

And also this :

```
 <select id="iSel" size="3">
     <option value="one">Un</option>
     <option value="two">Deux</option>
     <option value="three">Trois</option>
 </select>


 <script type="text/javascript"> "use strict";
    const i=document.getElementById("iSel");
    for(let k=0;k<i.length;k++) {
        if(k == i.selectedIndex) console.log("Selected ".repeat(3));
        console.log(`${Object.entries(i.options)[k][1].value}`+
                    ` => ` +
                    `${Object.entries(i.options)[k][1].innerHTML}`);
        console.log(Object.values(i.options)[k].value ,
                    " => ",
                    Object.values(i.options)[k].innerHTML);
        console.log("=".repeat(25));
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
myNewFunction = function(id, index) {
    var selection = document.getElementById(id);
    alert(selection.options[index].innerHTML);
};
```

See [here jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LyM9X/) sample

Comment: Why is everybody insisting on innerHTML??? Use .text ! And why pass all that stuff to the function. Just pass (this) and have the function decide what to use

Comment: Eh, I think it might be better/faster but I'd like to hear @mplungjan's rebuttal.

Comment: innerHTML is a convenience method invented by Microsoft. It was then copied to more browsers, but since a) it is not standard and b) you cannot have html in an option there is absolutely no need to confuse the issue when an option has .value and .text

Comment: `innerHTML` is so convenient though... I'm willing to sacrifice all of the standards and simplicity for that. :P

Comment: personally I use .text() with jQuery and .innerHTML with pure JS and helps me avoiding mistakes when mixmatching frameworks, only by habit. I  know innerHTML works in all browsers and that makes me happy :) oh and I specified both function parameters so that the OP can relate easier to my solution, no other reason.

Comment: .text works in more browsers than innerHTML and I find it confusing that you would use innerHTML to get the text of something that cannot have HTML in it

Comment: I do not know where you get your facts, but innerHTML support is fine by only a single exception "In IE and Konqueror innerHTML does not work correctly when you update tables". It's faster but I agree to .text for something that has no HTML in it.