# Why is my output undefined

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to figure this out. I am getting an `undefined` instead of `philadelphia` output on this script.

```
<center>
<form NAME="logform">
<select SIZE="1" NAME="store">
<option name='Philadelphia' id ='Joe Smith' value='philly@store.com'>Philadelphia</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="button" VALUE="Send email"
ONCLICK="location.href = &quot;mailto:&quot; +
document.logform.store.options
[document.logform.store.selectedIndex].
value + &quot;?subject=I would like to buy the &quot; +
document.logform.store.options
[document.logform.store.selectedIndex].
name + &quot; location &quot;"
NAME="Send email">
</form>
</center>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: never put JS inside HTML :(

Comment: Use  `getElementById()`

Comment: I'm still new to JS sorry but any help is appreciated I am able to call the value but not the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
document.logform.store.options[document.logform.store.selectedIndex].name
```

Use:

```
document.logform.store.options[document.logform.store.selectedIndex].text
```

Notice that just `.name` at the end was replaced by `.text`.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```html
<center>
<form NAME="logform">
<select SIZE="1" NAME="store">
<option name='Philadelphia' id ='Joe Smith' value='philly@store.com'>Philadelphia</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="button" VALUE="Send email"
ONCLICK="location.href = &quot;mailto:&quot; +
document.logform.store.options
[document.logform.store.selectedIndex].
value + &quot;?subject=I would like to buy the &quot; +
document.logform.store.options[document.logform.store.selectedIndex].text + &quot; location &quot;"
NAME="Send email">
</form>
</center>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14976638/586051)

Comment: Thank you! I will be accepting your answer as soon as it lets me. May I ask why it needs to be `.text` instead of `.name`?

Comment: @hyperj123 If you check the [MDN documentation for `<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option), `name` is not a valid attribute of `<option>`. So, to get the option text, they have provided `.text`.