# new to html I want to show what was selected in <select>

Tags: javascript, html, select

I want to show The licorice flavor, chocolate color, and topping chosen. I.e. "Green apple, white, christmas sprinkles."

please help not sure if i should have given each option a numeric value. I just did it just because. Feel free to change it to text or whatever you feel will work. I would love some advice on structuring if you see anything. Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="Licorice Flavors">
<select id="Licorice">
<option selected disabled>Licorice Flavor</option>
<option value="1">Green Apple</option>
<option value="2">Blue Raspberry</option>
<option value="3">Red Raspberry</option>
<option value="4">Watermelon</option>
<option value="5">Chocolate</option>
<option value="6">Orange</option>
<option value="7">Piña Colada</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="Chocolate Color">
<select id="Chocolate">
<option selected disabled>Chocolate Color</option>
<option value="8">White Chocolate</option>
<option value="9">Dark Chocolate</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="Toppings">
<select id="Toppings">
<option selected disabled>Toppings</option>
<option value="10">Christmas Sprinkles</option>
<option value="11">Rainbow Sprinkles</option>
<option value="12">Valentine's Day</option>
</select>
</div>

<a href="#" id="link">Add to Cart</a>
<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('link').onclick = function() {

    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('Licorice').value);
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('Chocolate').value);
    var c = parseInt(document.getElementById('Toppings').value);

    var answer = (a,b,c);



        document.getElementById('result').innerText = answer;

};
</script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: have 3 <select> menu like this http://imgur.com/RLPKWMu and i just want the result to show what I have selected text form. Then eventually want to give that combination a value as like an item number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close. Try this:

```
   var answer = [a,b,c].join(" ");
   document.getElementById('result').innerText = answer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-a-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery) if you can use jquery or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976495/get-selected-option-text-with-javascript) if you are using javascript only

Using the code from the link

```
<script>
    function myNewFunction(sel)
    {
        alert(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);
    }
</script>

<select id="box1" onChange="myNewFunction(this);" >
    <option value="98">dog</option>
    <option value="7122">cat</option>
    <option value="142">bird</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I guesh you want to do this.**

```js
document.getElementById('link').onclick = function() {

    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('Licorice').value);
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('Chocolate').value);
    var c = parseInt(document.getElementById('Toppings').value);

    var answer = "("+a + "," + b + ","+ c +")";



        document.getElementById('result').innerText = answer;

};
```

```html
<div class="Licorice Flavors">
<select id="Licorice">
<option selected disabled>Licorice Flavor</option>
<option value="1">Green Apple</option>
<option value="2">Blue Raspberry</option>
<option value="3">Red Raspberry</option>
<option value="4">Watermelon</option>
<option value="5">Chocolate</option>
<option value="6">Orange</option>
<option value="7">Piña Colada</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="Chocolate Color">
<select id="Chocolate">
<option selected disabled>Chocolate Color</option>
<option value="8">White Chocolate</option>
<option value="9">Dark Chocolate</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="Toppings">
<select id="Toppings">
<option selected disabled>Toppings</option>
<option value="10">Christmas Sprinkles</option>
<option value="11">Rainbow Sprinkles</option>
<option value="12">Valentine's Day</option>
</select>
</div>

<a href="#" id="link">Add to Cart</a>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('link').onclick = function() {

    var a = document.getElementById('Licorice').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('Chocolate').value;
    var c = document.getElementById('Toppings').value;

    var answer = [a,b,c].join(", ");



        document.getElementById('result').innerText = answer;

};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/fnq3smap/)

Comment: sorry i cant upvote i dont have enough reputation, however gladsocc also gave a very similar answer a little earlier. But I do appreciate your help very much. Thank you