# How get option text from select?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

how i can get the text selected from select tag?

```
<select id="51" class="toque">
    <option value="1">Save</option>
    <option value="2">Delete</option>                                    
</select>
```

I want to get the text between option tag (Save or Delete).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected option text with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976495/get-selected-option-text-with-javascript)

Comment: [Retrieving the text of the selected <option> in <select> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610336/retrieving-the-text-of-the-selected-option-in-select-element)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var sel = document.getElementById("51");
var text= sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('51').selectedOptions[0].text;
```

Comment: dont want to get the value param, but the text value between the tag.

Comment: I'd recommend closing this question in favor of [Retrieving the text of the selected <option> in <select> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610336/retrieving-the-text-of-the-selected-option-in-select-element). Especially for very general questions like this there are already going to be very thorough answers with multiple solutions and the cost/benefits of each. You should spend some more time searching before asking in the future to help keep StackOverflow more focused and organized.