# Retrieve the option name instead of the value in Local Storage JavaScript when using Select2 widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code to store the selections of the Select2 widget in my Local Storage:

```
// watch for changes to locations select
$('#locations').change(function() {
    var selected = []; // create an array to hold all currently selected locations

    // loop through each available location
    $('#locations option').each(function() {
        // if it's selected, add it to the array above
        if (this.selected) {
            selected.push(this.value);
        }
    });

    // store the array of selected options
    localStorage.setItem('locations', JSON.stringify(selected));
});
```

The problem is that this is my HTML generated by Django:

```
<select name="preferred_location_test" id="locations" multiple="">
  <option value="7">The Netherlands</option>
  <option value="9">France</option>
</select>
```

So I my local storage I get "7" and "9", but I want this to be the option text, so "The Netherlands" or "France". How can I apply this to my code? I am not very good with JavaScript. I tried these SO posts:

[Get selected option text with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976495/get-selected-option-text-with-javascript)

[Retrieving the text of the selected <option> in <select> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610336/retrieving-the-text-of-the-selected-option-in-select-element)

But they use selectIndex, and I am not sure how I can use that in my code.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with `<select>` in jquery you use `$(this).value` instead of`this.value` to get the content of `value` attribute.

to get the actual displayed text, use `$(this).text() instead.

refer to this snippet

```
    $('#locations option').each(function() {
        // if it's selected, add it to the array above
        if (this.selected) {
            var location = $(this).text();
            selected.push(location);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Great! This is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let selected_values = [];
$("#locations").on('change', function() {
  $('#locations :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
    selected_values[i] = $(selected).text();
});
  alert(selected_values);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="preferred_location_test" id="locations" multiple="">
  <option value="7">The Netherlands</option>
  <option value="9">France</option>
</select>
```

So if you need text of option you can simply use `$("#test option:selected").html()`

```js
$("#test").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '1') {
     alert($("#test option:selected").html());
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option value="1">Test</option>
  <option value="2">1Test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just use $("#locations option:selected").html(); to get the option text

Comment: done. Please check not you can store the alert value in localStorage