# Select Bootstrap Search Event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

i have a bit problem with a `select` search of bootstrap, i need get the value of the search.

```
 <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
        <select class="form-control bootstrap-select" data-live-search="true" asp-for="Client" asp-items=@ViewBag.clients></select>
 </div>
```

i'm trying to get into a `change` event, but only can get the id and the value of the option, but not of the search value...

```
$("#Client").change(function () {
     alert(this.value);
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976495/get-selected-option-text-with-javascript#

Comment: ty @FerhatBAŞ, but don't need get the value of the option, i need the search value, i'm using data-live-search

Comment: Ok, i was my mistake, if you want to get input value as live you should use keyup event chnage event when input leaved than fired.

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ don't worry, you have any example of the change event can help me?

Comment: i havent use asp but is there an input when you start search it has to added dynamically inspect it dev tools then catch classname or any indentically value and use keyup like this $('#Client findedindecallyvalue').keyup()

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ sorry, but don't work, ty for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the search value in live-search textbox by this:

```js
$("#Client").change(function () {
    alert($(".bs-searchbox").find("input").val());
});
```

Comment: @jmoyau if this helps you, please accept my answer as the best, thanks.