# Javascript select from tag select by text

Tags: javascript, html

I have to make javascript, select from one of this options by the text that is written,(Small, Medium, Large, Xlarge)
**not** by the value, can someone please help me :)

```
<option value="s">Small</option>
<option value="M">Medium</option>
<option value="L">Large</option>
<option value="XL">XLarge</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you provide some context? Like how you want it? You want the exact same as this but generated in JS?

Comment: Add the javascript code that you have tried and explain what it is doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get selected option text with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976495/get-selected-option-text-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll("select option").forEach(option => {
  option.text === "Medium" ? option.selected=true  : option;
})
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="s">Small</option>
  <option value="M">Medium</option>
  <option value="L">Large</option>
  <option value="XL">XLarge</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

This creates the exact same that you provided, just add more options.

```js
let options = [{ name: 'small', value: 's' }, { name: 'medium', value: 'm' }]
var dropdown = document.createElement('select');
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(dropdown)

function addOpt(option, parentElement) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.setAttribute('value', `${option.value}`)
    opt.innerText = option.name
    parentElement.appendChild(opt)
}

options.forEach(option =>
    addOpt(option, dropdown)
)
```