# how I can get the content the select from the value

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

i  have this select

```
 <select id="health">
     <option value=0>Select</option>
     <option value="1">Green</option>
     <option value="2">Amber</option>
     <option value="3">Red</option>
   </select>
```

i need to use jquery to get the content each opent for example Green or Amber etc ..
i want want when the user sent a the value the option , he will get the content this option

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976495/get-selected-option-text-with-javascript

Comment: jquery solution - `$('#health').on('change', function() {
console.log($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});`

Comment: thank you ,but i need when the user send the value for example 0,1 or3 ... then he will get the content

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get selected option text with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976495/get-selected-option-text-with-javascript)