# Getting emoji from <select> <option> value as an <empty string>

Tags: javascript, html

I have a selector with only emojis as options, and when trying to get the value in JS (the emoji the user picked) the console is printing it as an empty string.

This is my HTML code for the selector:

```
<select id="iconSelector">
     <option value=""></option> 
     <option value=""></option>    
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value=""></option>     
     <option value=""></option>   
</select>
```

And this is my JS code for getting the value:

```
const addTaskBtn = document.querySelector("#newTaskBtn");
addTaskBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let taskName = document.querySelector('#taskInput').value;
    let taskIcon = document.querySelector('#iconSelector').value;
    console.log(taskName);
    console.log(taskIcon); // Getting <empty string> in console.log
    document.querySelector('#taskInput').value = '';
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14976638/13873643

```
var sel = document.getElementById("box1");
var text= sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: you are not getting the value here, if you want to leverage on forms that’s an antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the value in the options are all empty strings. You may want to set it to:

```
<select id="iconSelector">
     <option value="box"></option> 
     <option value="piano"></option>    
     <option value="books"></option>
     <option value="dog"></option>     
     <option value="car"></option>
```

And then, you'll see the value.