# How do I get an AJAX request argument in Flask server?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flask

Im getting the request at the backened but unable to know the value. i tried many variations of request but nothing grants me the value of cars.

my flask file

```
import ssl
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, jsonify, request
from flask_dance.contrib.facebook import make_facebook_blueprint, facebook
from flask_dance.contrib.google import make_google_blueprint, google

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='app', static_url_path="/app")
app.secret_key = "secret"  # Replace this with your own secret!

@app.route('/appoint', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def appoint(name='appoint'):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_data(as_text=True)
        print(data)
    return render_template("appoint.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    context = ssl.SSLContext() 
    context.load_cert_chain('/etc/letsencrypt/live/annastudio.beauty/fullchain.pem', '/etc/letsencrypt/live/annastudio.beauty/privkey.pem') 
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=443, ssl_context=context)
```

my ajax call and the inputs

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


        <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
        <select id="cars">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="opel">Opel</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="loadDoc()">
      

<script>
  function loadDoc() {
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("cars").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
    
  xhttp.open("POST", "https://www.annastudio.beauty/appoint", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[there is a 200 code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDh3w.jpg)

I was expecting to get value of one of the cars.`I was able to use form but it has a refresh on page.

Edit:
Thank you Jaromanda x this solves it

```
    <html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


        <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
        <select id="cars">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="opel">Opel</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="loadDoc()">
      

<script>
  function loadDoc() {
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const data = document.getElementById("cars").innerHTML;
  xhttp.open("POST", "https://www.annastudio.beauty/appoint", true);
  xhttp.send(data);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[now it gets me all the options! how do I get only what the user selects?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wAvp.jpg)

edit:

```
<script>
  var sel = document.getElementById("cars");
  var text = sel.value;
```

[Get selected option text with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976495/get-selected-option-text-with-javascript)

Comment: you'll need to send something in `xhttp.send();` ... hows the server supposed to know which option you selected?

Comment: `xhttp.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("cars").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }` i tell xhttp to getElementById...what else should I send?

Comment: it's a POST request? then you need to POST something in `xhttp.send();`

Comment: have you checked what `document.getElementById("cars").innerHTML;` actually is? it's not what you want to send ... you need `document.getElementById("cars").value`